# Open Apple Maps and Start Route from Current Location to Home Immediately in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios6-maps

I'm wanting to create a link in my application that essentially will be labelled "Take Me Home". When pressed, I want it to open Apple Maps, route from current location to home, and start turn by turn navigation.

I have found this scheme, but it does not do everything I was hoping for:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f
```

Comment: Just to be clear what your problem is, you aren't getting Maps to start turn-by-turn navigation by simply opening that URL?

Comment: @Nate correct. I can get the route to show up, but the user still has to press "Start"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working code for opening Maps with routes (including the option to show Google maps for iOS5)

```
-(IBAction)showMapApp:(id)sender
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.location.latitude,self.location.longitude);

//create MKMapItem out of coordinates
MKPlacemark* placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem* destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

if([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:)])
{
    //using iOS6 native maps app
    if(_mode == 1)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking}];

    }
    if(_mode == 2)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

    }
    if(_mode == 3)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

    }

} else{

    //using iOS 5 which has the Google Maps application
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%f,%f", self.location.latitude, self.location.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
}
```

Comment: Hi its working fine but marker is not added in map.I want to show the routes like http://cdn.macrumors.com/article-new/2015/10/sydney_apple_maps_transit.jpg?retina

Answer (score 0):

Use this For me its working fine::

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=44.521358,11.374080&daddr=44.518640,11.362665"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```